# Error when using network stream.write

Tags: c#, java, sockets, tcp, bufferedreader

First thats a part of my server code :

```
while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
 rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);
                        serverResponse = "Server to clinet(" + clNo + ") " + " are u there ?" + Environment.NewLine;
                        sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                       networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                       networkStream.Flush();
                        Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(" >> error :  " + ex.Message);
                }


            }
```

and this is my code on client side :

```
    String k= null; 

     try {

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
          k = br.readLine();          
          System.out.println(k);

      }
     catch (IOException f) {
System.out.println("error is :  "+f.getMessage());

    }     
    catch (Exception g) {

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Server is offline","Alert !",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    }
```

the error here is that my program is entering in a unfinish loop 
and keep saying in server output ... ">> Server to clinet(1)  are u there ?"

Also my client application is freezing whithout receiving the message .. !
any help ? thx :) ( btw my client is on java ana my server is on c# )

Comment: Are you satisfied with the formating of your codes?

Comment: @I4V im new with connections.. so im using google to make that .. !
All i need is a little help to tell me where did u make the error .. !